# Ajax problems in Safari and Firefox

Tags: .net, ajax, firefox, com, safari

I have a form submission generated from COM in an asp page.  The end of the form submission looks like the following:

```
IFrame1.contentWindow.SaveChanges();
IFrame2.contentWindow.SaveChanges();
return true;
```

The SaveChanges function issues an AJAX call to a .net AjaxPro method.  In IE and Chrome this works fine, but in FF and Safari, they both result in communications errors, presumably because the HTTP connection they were operating on has been dropped.  I tried to change them from AjaxPro to jQuery in order to get more info, but the error just reports communication failure.

The idea I had to solve the problem was to chain them together as such with SaveChanges accepting and calling a callback function:

```
IFrame1.contentWindow.SaveChanges(IFrame2.contentWindow.SaveChanges(return true));
```

But not only will no browser accept this javascript, even if it did work, it wouldn't accomplish my goal as the return true would be run in the context of IFrame2.contentWindow.SaveChanges(), not in the context of the ASP page.

I don't need to wait for the AJAX call to finish running, but I do need to wait to return true until SaveChanges() has made the AJAX call to actually issue the return true;

Comment: return IFrame1.contentWindow.SaveChanges(IFrame2.contentWindow.SaveChanges()) still does not work in FF & Safari. Verified that the new approach still works in IE.

Answer (score 0):

I'd usually let this go a little longer, but I'm up against a deadline.  I finally ended up converting the AJAX calls to synchronous (SJAX?).